# baking multiple materials in cycles, UV map overlap makes renderder baked image tile

Tags: uv-image-editor

PLEASE HELP... i have modeled a wall and assigned 2 materials to it with the principle shader, one for the face of the wall and a separate for the trim

pic:[image: UV map of white plank boards are scaled along the X axis to fit the illusion of smaller boards. from what i understand this is ok.]

both materials are SMART UV UNWRAPPED with only the white boards being scaled outside the image texture ( for board alignment, its my understanding this is ok, a way to fake resolution even in certain cases)

now when i create the new UV image for the image texture to reference and bake to, i create a new uv image, and UV SMART UNWRAP the entire mesh, however the UV maps are overlaying.

after baking, and creating a duplicate of the mesh with materials removed and replaced with the baked image texture through a diffuse node

PIC:[image: background is original mesh with material nodes, foreground is a object duplicate with materials removed and the baked image applied.]

PLEASE HELP ME CREATE A MAP THAT WILL NOT CAUSE THIS< IM LOST :(

Comment: I HAVE FIGURED IT OUT, ADDON CALLED TEXTURE ATLAS

Comment: When inserting screenshots please crop them and don't use Caps Lock